# Unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, python-3.4

Objectives: I need to read cost and discount rate and number of year and calculate the time adjusted cost and time adjusted benefits and cumulative for both.

I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\codetest\hw.py", line 3, in <module>
    cost = eval(input("Enter Development cost :"))
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

When I remove `eval` the code works fine.

```
 #import numpy as np

cost = eval(input("Enter Development cost :"))
discrate = eval(input("Enter discount rate :"))

#operation cost list
opcost = []
#benifits list
benifits = []
#dicount rate list


#dicount rate list
discount=[]
#time adjusted cost
TAC = []
#time adjusted benifits
TAB = []

CTAC=[]

year = eval(input("Enter number of year "))

for i in range (year):
    opcost.append(eval(input("Enter operation cost :")))

for i in range (year):
    benifits.append(eval(input("Enter benifit for this year :")))



for i in range (year):
    pvn = (1/pow(1+discrate,i))
    # print (pvn)
    discount.append(pvn)

for i in range (year):
    TAC.append(discount[i] * opcost[i])

#print(TAC[i])

for i in range(year):
    TAB.append(discount[i] * benifits[i]))


#CTAC = np.cumsum(TAC)

#for i in range (year):
#    print(CTAC[i])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `eval()`, Python tries to parse the string you pass to it as a Python expression. You passed in an *empty string*:

```
>>> eval('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Rather than use `eval()` you should use a specific converter; if your costs are floating point values then use `float()` instead:

```
opcost.append(float(input("Enter operation cost :")))
```

This can still cause errors if the user just hits <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and you get another empty string:

```
>>> float('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

You can still handle that case by catching the exception. See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for more details on how to best do this, including how to handle repeatedly asking until valid input is given.

Comment: the error is :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\codetest\hw.py", line 3, in <module>
    cost = eval(input("Enter Development cost :"))
  File "<string>", line 0
    
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @MoathWafeeq: then you had *empty input* as well as a missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: @MoathWafeeq: this is why you should **always** include the full error message in your post.

Comment: Yes, this is my first question in this website.

Comment: @MoathWafeeq: updated address your actual problem. Do edit your question to add the error message (and fix that closing `)` you apparently missed when copying the code).